# Help Factoring A Difficult Expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, factoring

Given  A = $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\c & a & b \\b & c & a \\\end{bmatrix}$, B =$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\a^4 & b^4 & c^4 \\\end{bmatrix}$

---

Suppose $C =AB=\begin{bmatrix}
a^2 + a^2b + a^4c & ab + b^3 + b^4c & ac +bc^2 + c^5 \\
\\
ca + a^3 +a^4b & cb + ab^2 + b^5 & c^2 + ac^2 +bc^4 \\
\\
ba + a^2c + a^5 & b^2 + b^2c + ab^4 & bc + c^3 + ac^4 
\end{bmatrix}$

---

I have been asked to show that the following holds:

---

$det(C)= -abc(b-c)(a-c)(a-b)(a^2-ab+b^2 -bc +c^2 -ac)(a+b+c)^2$

---

The way i proceeded to go about this is using the fact that $det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$.Now finding the determinant of A and B i have the following.

---

$det(A)= a^3 -3abc +b^3 +c^3$

---

$det(B) = abc(c^3b - cb^3 - c^3a + ca^3 + b^3a - ba^3)$

---

The problem i have is factoring out the necessary factors from the product of the determinants. I have tried loads of methods now and i have got nowhere and am a bit depressed by it. Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we have
$$
\det(A)=(a^2 - ab - ac + b^2 - bc + c^2)(a + b + c),
$$

$$
\det(B)=(a + b + c)(a - b)(a - c)(b - c)abc.
$$

Comment: i'm not sure how to get the det(B) into that form though.

Comment: I know how to get the determinant i just don't know how to factorize it

Comment: Just extract each factor. Start with $abc$, then $a-b$ etc.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any common factors though :(

Comment: Not true. If you set $b=a$, then the polynomial in $a,b,c$ is zero. Hence $a-b$ is a factor.

Comment: Ah that is a great method i didn't know i could do that to find factors, thank you very much does that work for say b = a + b to try get the a + b + c term out ?

Comment: got it if i set c =-(a+b) i get the other factor out, how do you know when you have all the factors though using this method?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

Comment: Thank you, so i need to somehow get det(A) into that form somehow ?

Comment: Yes this is right, can you factor the other term?

Comment: Ok so i have the det(A) now thank you greatly just going to see if i can use the above equality to get something for det(B) :)

Comment: $$\det(B)$$ was posted already.